# JavaScript .map() syntax error

Tags: javascript, arrays

new to JS.

I'm using google script to create a function that will input a string will output the interger in it (if any). In order to optimize for google script, I've read suggestions on allowing also ranges as input.

I'm getting an error when using .map, but I can't figure out what it is. Any help. I've been looking for more examples of the use of map but none were helpfull.

Any idea?

thanks everyone

```js
if (input.map) {
  input.map(
    if (isInt(split[i])) {
      result = split[i]
    });
} else {
  for (i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if (isInt(split[i])) {
      result = split[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First parameter of `map` is a `function` what you have is an `expression`[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: If the code doesn’t actually modify your `input` array, then `forEach` is better suited than `map`.

Comment: You cannot use **statements** as function arguments. Have you ever seen code that looks like `foo(if(true) { ... })`. That doesn't make sense. MDN usually has examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you should pass function as parameter,

```
input.map(function() {
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> will input a string will output the interger in it (if any)

Try using `isNaN` , `Number()` , `Array.prototype.filter()` , `typeof` to return `Number` values

```js
var arr = ["1", "a", "0"];
var res = arr.map(function(n) {
  return !isNaN(Number(n)) && Number(n)
}).filter(function(n) {
  return typeof n === "number"
});
console.log(res)
```